# Why is Cinderella called Ella in "Once Upon a Time"?

Tags: character, once-upon-a-time

In *Once Upon a Time*, characters' names were kept as they are in the fairy world from Prince Charming to Rumpelstiltskin. But why is Cinderella called by the name of "Ella" by all the characters?

Comment: Isn't it is just a diminutive?

Comment: @Hegemon but why only here, not others.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've heard them use it in other versions... including in the most recent [Cinderella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinderella_%282015_film%29) film.

Comment: "Snow White" is just called "Snow" (she was never referred to as "Snow" in the animated film)... Belle calls Rumpelstiltskin "Rumple". Ella's not the only one who has a shortened name.

Comment: "Snow White" **is** her first name. In English, we have common compound first names like "Mary Ann". You can't just call someone named "Mary Ann" "Mary" and have it be the same thing. "Snow White" isn't an actual first name, but her last name is not "White". As far as I know, none of the royals have anything other than first names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Possibly because "Cinderella" was a [mean-spirited nickname given by her stepsisters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinderella#Cendrillon.2C_by_Perrault), and others, especially friends, wouldn't be so cruel. The stepsisters called her that because she was forced to sleep in the cinders by the fireplace, leaving her dirty. "Cinderella" meant something like "little cinder girl".

It's not clear what Cinderella's real name is supposed to have been. But since "Ella" is a modern first name it's a reasonable choice. One example where it's used is the old [Ella Cinders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ella_Cinders) comic strip. This name is really a [back formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-formation) to "Cinder Ella", since it doesn't seem to be part of the original stories. But since those stories didn't give her real name, it's not a bad idea.